# Access custom page configuration from content element in Fluid TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I'm currently using TYPO3 6.2.10 with Fluid.
Now i have encountered a problem I can not find any solution to in the documentation:

I have special configuration fields defined in my page template and try to access them from within a custom fluid content element.
Problem being, that none of the fields are showing up in the `v:page.info` or any other viewhelper I could find.

Do you guys have any solution oder advice?
Thanks in advance!

---

update 05.05.:

The data I want to access - here the field example - is set in the configuration section of the page:

```
  <f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="page_landing">
      <flux:field.input name="example" />
    </flux:form>
    <flux:grid>
      <flux:grid.row>
        <flux:grid.column colPos="0" name="main_col" />
        <flux:grid.column colPos="1" name="side_col" />
      </flux:grid.row>
    </flux:grid>
  </f:section>
```

If it is not possible to access this data from an element on another page, then is there a diffrent way for the user to save data page wise and access it from an FCE?

Comment: I have used this once: `<v:variable.set name="pageData" value="{flux:form.data(table: 'pages', field: 'tx_fed_page_flexform', uid: pageUid)}"/>` - but I think it is not safe, e.g. it could make problems if the settings are done on a parent page... maybe you could try that out?

Comment: What do you mean with "special configuration fields defined in my page template"? Can you explain what you actually did? Is it a flexform? Is the value correctly stored in the XML structure in the database record of that page?

Comment: @Michael I updated my original post to provide further information. Basically any way of storing data on the page in the backend with the ability to access them from a FCE on other pages will do.

Comment: @Michael Not quite, but the tip to add `arguments="{_all}"` to the FCE `f:render` actually activated the tx_fed_page_flexform field with the needed information in xml. So I guess I'm going to write an own viewhelper to extract the data from the xml. Thank you very much!